# What is the best way of renaming (alias/forward) a function in C++?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates, perfect-forwarding

(I'll restrict this question to C++11, since I believe there is no general way to do this in C++98).

Supposed I have a complicated (in terms of signature) set of *template* functions and/or overloaded functions, and I want to use these functions in the exact same way but using a different name (that is, an alias).

For example:

```
template<class A, class B, class C> 
D fun(A a, B& b, C&& c){ ... }

template<class E, class F> 
G fun(H<E> he, F& f){ ... }

... many other versions of fun
```

Now suppose that I want to *rename* (or *alias*, or *forward* to be more precise) these functions, all at once (i.e. be able to use a different name for the same function without rewriting it). Such that, in other parts of the code I can use it with a different name and without modifying the above code.

Is this the correct way to *rename* (alias/forward) `fun` into `gun`?

```
template<typename... Args> 
inline auto gun(Args&&... args)->decltype(fun(std::forward<Args>(args)...)){
    return fun(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

- Is it truly general?
- Is this the simplest way?
- Is this the optimal way? (e.g. can be inlined, no unnecessary copies)
- What if the original function had some SFINAE features? (e.g. `template<class A, class B, class C, class = std::enable_if< ... >::type>`), will `decltype` transfer the SFINAE in all cases?
- What if the original function returned references? Isn't the decltype going to remove the references type?. (e.g. `double& fun(double& x){return x;}`).
- Can same be said about member functions?

Clarification: `gun` is never going to be *exactly* `fun`, as the instances will have different addresses, but what I am looking for is a rename for the point of view of generic coding.

Comment: I find strange that almost everything can be renamed/forwarded, namespaces, types (`typedef`) and template types `using typedef`, but not functions (or for that matter member functions).

---

**EDIT**: For completeness, and since this seems to be the way to do it, here I added a macro to define function aliases:

```
#define ALIAS_FUNCTION(OriginalnamE, AliasnamE) \
template <typename... Args> \
inline auto AliasnamE(Args&&... args) -> decltype(OriginalnamE(std::forward<Args>(args)...)) { \
  return OriginalnamE(std::forward<Args>(args)...); \
}
```

and then you use it like this:

```
namespace NS1{namepsace NS2{
  ALIAS_FUNCTION(NSA::fun, gun); // second argument (target name can't have namespace)
}}
```

---

**EDIT2:** I think exception policy can be incorporated in the alias as well:

```
#define ALIAS_FUNCTION(OriginalnamE, AliasnamE) \
template <typename... Args> \
inline auto AliasnamE(Args&&... args) \
  noexcept(OriginalnamE(std::forward<Args>(args)...)) \
->decltype(OriginalnamE(std::forward<Args>(args)...)){\
    return OriginalnamE(std::forward<Args>(args)...);}
```

but didn't test it yet.
[You must type it three times](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I3T4lePH-yA).

Comment: I think this is fine. `decltype` gets the correct type (i.e. `&` for a function that returns an lvalue reference, `&&` for a function that returns an rvalue reference, and non-reference otherwise).

Comment: Please, you'll make life a lot easier for everyone if you describe what you're actually doing. You're not renaming *anything*. The original name still exists. You're forwarding, or providing an alias or a wrapper function. None of this has anything to do with renaming. Renaming implies *changing* the name, making the old name go away in favor of a new one

Comment: @jalf, good point. I guess, it is harder to make the original name to go away. As the only way I imagine is to enclose the original definition into an unnamed namespace. But yes, that was not the idea.

Comment: From my understanding, it should... but *everytime* and the C++ standard don't mesh well enough for me to provide any guarantee :x

Comment: The implementation itself looks fine to me, but you should also declare it `inline`.  Template functions aren't implicitly declared `inline` unless they're defined inside a class, so if you want the compiler to inline the functions generated from `gun`, you have to say so. (Compilers are permitted to inline functions not declared `inline`, but if you want to maximize the likelihood that `gun` will be inlined, explicitly using `inline` seems prudent.)

Comment: I think `#define gun fun` is okay. It works everywhere.

Comment: @zch, the problem I see with `#define` is that it will add the name `gun` even in contexts where `fun` is not used as function, isn't it?

Comment: @KnowItAllWannabe, I added the `inline` to make the code more complete in the question.

Comment: @alfC: I agree. I did suggest "alias" in my comment too. :)

Comment: Since you are clearly a beginner, I have not downvoted, but: I cannot answer your question because your code does not even compile. Please read the help section and provide an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). ;-)

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica no problem, the question has been answered already, some time ago.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> Is it truly general?

Yes.

> Is this the simplest way?

Yes (sadly).

> Is this the optimal way? (e.g. can be inlined, no unnecessary copies)

Yes.

> What if the original function had some SFINAE features? (e.g. `template<class A, class B, class C, class = std::enable_if< ... >::type>`), will decltype transfer the SFINAE in all cases?

Yes, if the expression inside `decltype` yields an error (i.e., `fun` doesn't exist, perhaps due to SFINAE on `fun`), this will trigger SFINAE for `gun` aswell, removing it from the overload set.

> What if the original function returned references? Isn't the decltype going to remove the references type?. (e.g. `double& fun(double& x){return x;}`).

No, why would it?

> Same can be said about member functions, although this has to be done modifying the class I guess.

This isn't a question. What can be said about member functions? All of the above applies equally.

Comment: +1 for the "sadly". Since I didn't receive an answer for the negative, I'll mark this as accepted.