# constexpr function pointer vs forward function

Tags: c++11, function-pointers, static-methods, static-members, constexpr

I need a template class that maps a family non-overloaded, non-template c-function into C++ template function in order to make subsequent code more generic:

For example suppose, a C-library has these function for a bunch of types:

```
c_fun_float(...)
c_gun_float(..)

c_fun_double(...)
c_gun_double(..)
```

That I want to generally call as

```
cpp<T>::fun(...)
cpp<T>::gun(..)
```

in C++11.

For that, I am using this pattern:

```
template<class T> cpp;

template<> cpp<double>{
    "static fun maps to c_fun_double"; // pseudo code
    "static gun maps to c_gun_double"; // pseudo code
};
template<> cpp<float>{
    "static fun maps to c_fun_float"; // pseudo code
    "static gun maps to c_gun_float"; // pseudo code
};
```

The question is how write this mapping code. The first attempt was (maybe abusing of C++11):

```
template<> cpp<double>{
    static constexpr auto fun = &c_fun_double; // nice short code!
    static constexpr auto gun = &c_gun_double;
};
... corresponding code for float ...
```

Which look pretty clean. However I later realized that these are pointers to functions not "real" functions (for example cannot be inlined?). On the other hand they are `constexpr` so maybe in effect it the can direct call (unlikely).

So I decided to change the code to

```
template<> cpp<double>{
    template<class... Args>
    static inline auto fun(Args&&... args) -> decltype(c_fun_double(std::forward<Args>(args)...)){
       return c_fun_double(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    } // lots of typing!
    template<class... Args>
    static inline auto gun(Args&&... args) -> decltype(c_gun_double(std::forward<Args>(args)...)){
       return c_gun_double(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
    // perhaps write a macro
};
... corresponding code for float ...
```

The question is, *what is better?* to have

1. **a static constexpr function pointer (less verbose, *may*(?) have indirect call penalty) or**
2. **a static inline perfect forward function (more verbose, but direct call, works with overloads if necessary).**

Is there an advantage in one approach over the other?

Maybe another way to put the question, **do `constexpr` pointers to function produce indirect calls via a runtime pointer?**

Comment: both sound like a micro optimization

Comment: If you care about the speed here, I would simply measure it. What I would be most concerned about would be readability.

Comment: Why do you bother perfectly forwarding something to a C function?

Comment: @T.C., sure, it is just that `static inline auto gun(Args&&... args){return c_gun_double(args...);}` sounded wrong.

Comment: @BЈовић, what do you mean by "both"? I really need the function call to be (template) generic from the C++ perspective.

Comment: First of all, I do not see what exactly is the problem, and this sounds like x-y question. To answer your last question : yes, it is still an indirect call (compile to assembly code and see what exactly is produced).

Comment: Ok, thanks @BЈовић, I think that answers the question. So the forward call is direct but the pointer is indirect even if it is `constexpr` (Sorry my ignorance, I don't know how to analyze the assembly code.) Besides I though that it could be up to the compiler to treat `constexpr` function pointers as direct calls.

Comment: @BЈовић, I also see your point, the question is confusing because it has the template aspect to it, maybe to illustrate a case but not fundamental. It could have been clear in the context of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13698989/what-is-the-best-way-of-renaming-alias-forward-a-function-in-c