# Create a renamed function from template function reference

Tags: c++, c++11

I don't really know how to rename the function below.
The example only works with template specialization.

```
    template<typename A, typename B>
    auto MAX(const A &one, const B &two) -> decltype(one > two ? one : two) {
        static_assert(std::is_floating_point<A>::value || std::is_integral<A>::value, "ERROR - bigger(): template parameters not of type float or int\n");
        static_assert(std::is_floating_point<B>::value || std::is_integral<B>::value, "ERROR - bigger(): template parameters not of type float or int\n"); 

        return one > two ? one : two;
    }

    template<typename A, typename B>
    const auto min = &MAX<A,B>;
```

Works:

```
    const auto min = &MAX<float,float>;
```

Comment: `template<typename A, typename B> const auto min = &MAX<A,B>;` should work with a C++14 compiler that supports variable templates.

Comment: "This doesn't work" is useless without what error messages you are getting.  Also useful is what compiler you get them from.

Comment: I do not think that your `decltype()` expression will work as expected because the values of `one` and `two` (barring some rare cases with `constexpr`) cannot be known at compile time.

Comment: Also, it does not make sense to name a function that calculates the maximum `min`. Is that a typo?

Comment: The name is just a dumb example.
Is there a Cxx11 way to solve this?

Comment: @JoelCornett An expression doesn't need to be evaluated in order to figure out its type. `decltype` very specifically does not evaluate its operand, just like `sizeof`.

Comment: `template<typename A, typename B> auto min(const A &one, const B &two) -> decltype(MAX<A, B>(one, two)) { return MAX<A, B>(one, two); }`

Comment: take a look at : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13698989/what-is-the-best-way-of-renaming-alias-forward-a-function-in-c

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: I didn't say that it wouldn't compile. I said it wouldn't work as expected because there is no way the order operation could be resolved at compile time. There is no way the resolved type would be correct.

Comment: @JoelCornett What is the "correct" type that you expect? Do you believe that the type of the expression `one > two ? one : two` depends on whether `one` is actually greater than `two`, and therefore may change at runtime? This is, of course, not the case - C++ is a statically typed language, types of all expressions are known at compile time. Do you also believe that the value of `sizeof(one > two ? one : two)` is determined at runtime? Try it, see for yourself.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik The expression as it stands doesn't make sense *because* the type will be determined at compile time. There's no reason for the expression in the first place -- it won't do what it "claims" to do.

Comment: @JoelCornett What do you believe the clause claims to do, and what do you believe it does instead? I don't at all understand the nature of your objection. As far as I can tell, the clause says "the return type of this function is the type that normal coercion rules for `?:` operator would produce given operands of types `A` and `B`". Do you read the clause as claiming something else, or do you believe that it does claim this, but doesn't actually deliver?