# Is there a technical reason for not allowing a using declaration to make a function name accessible under a different name?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

Consider

```
namespace foo
{
  namespace bar
  {
    void f();
    void f(int);
  }
}
```

In `foo` one can make all `foo::bar::f` accessible as `foo::f` via

```
using bar::f; // in foo
```

Is there any technical reason for the nonexistence of a syntax that makes all `foo::bar::f` accessible as `foo::g` like

```
using bar::f as g; 
// or in line with using declarations for types:
using g = bar::f;
```

or has something like this even been considered but rejected? (Why?)

Comment: Workaround: `auto g = [](auto ...args){ foo::bar::f(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...); };`

Comment: @KerrekSB: Introducing a `g` which matches possibly far more than any `f`.

Comment: @Pixelchemist Well, one can employ SFINAE to circumvent that.

Comment: @Pixelchemist: Yes, it would produce a quite different overload set.

Comment: @KerrekSB `g` cannot be overloaded, but making `g` a function template would still have different semantics, since non-template functions are preferred in overload resolution (and one could need to overload `g`).

Comment: The background to the question is the need to push a function into a nested namespace in order to make `using std::f;` available for trailing return types and `constexpr` specification. I'd like to drag those out of the enclosing namespace under a different name since the function they are mimicing has the same name in `std`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13698989/what-is-the-best-way-of-renaming-alias-forward-a-function-in-c

Comment: @Serthy: A general template isn't resolving the issue since I got several templace classes in namespace `A` that should have an overload for a function set (including i.e. `abs`) with noexcept specifications. I have the functions in a sub-namespace `A::B` importing the required function from `std` (i.e. `using std::abs;`) in order to use `std`-defaulted but ADL-capable `abs(...)` in the noexcept specification for `c_abs`. In `A` I have `C abs(C const &c) noexcept(noexcept(B::c_abs(c))) -> decltype(B::c_abs(c)) { return B::c_abs(c); }`. It would be handy to say `using abs = B::c_abs;` instead.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

See [**N1489**](http://www.stroustrup.com/template-aliases.pdf):

> It is possible to generalize the notion of alias beyond types and
>   namespaces to functions, variables, etc. We do not see sufficient
>   benefits from doing this and can imagine serious overuse leading to
>   confusion about which functions and variables are used. Consequently,
>   we do not propose the generalizations mentioned in this section.
>   Furthermore, we do not plan to work further on these generalizations
>   unless someone comes up with examples that indicate significant
>   usefulness.

Comment: In other words: `using` is intended for just types. The technical reason is fear of abuse/overuse.

Comment: @einpoklum There is no technical reason (i.e. obstacle). It just wouldn't constitute an improvement

Answer (score 11):

I can't think of any technical reasons for this not existing, I think it's a question of suitable (non-clashing) syntax and a significantly important use-case.

There is currently a [standards proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/p0109r0.pdf) to add function aliases to the language in order to support *opaque typedefs*. According to that paper, the feature was previously considered in the early 90s, but rejected:

> Stroustrup described [function aliasing] in his D&E book as a “renaming” feature in the context of resolving name clashes due to multiple
>   inheritance: “The semantics of this concept are simple, and the implementation is trivial; the
>   problem seems to be to find a suitable syntax.” He states that such a proposal “was presented
>   at the standards meeting in Seattle in 1990” and that, although there was initially “a massive
>   majority,” the feature was ultimately not adopted: “At the next meeting, . . . we agreed that such
>   name clashes were unlikely to be common enough to warrant a separate language feature.”

The syntax proposed is as follows:

```
template< class RA, class R = std::less<> >
void
sort( RA b, RA const e, R lt = {} )
{
    using operator<() = lt; // operator < has type R
    // Remaining code in this scope uses infix < in place of calls to lt().
    // (A future proposal may suggest synthesis of other relational
    // operators from an operator< declared in this fashion.)
}
```

Perhaps someone who attended recent standards meetings could weigh in on what the reaction to the proposal was.

Comment: https://isocpp.org/blog/2015/11/kona-standards-meeting-trip-report "Opaque types (P0109R0). Rejected for being far too complex for the problem solved."